# How to not allow duplicates in ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and EF so this may be a really simple question but what is the best way to prevent the user from trying to enter duplicate records?

I have a table called `Category` with two columns `Id` and `CategoryName` (`Id` is the PK and I set the index value to unique on `CategoryName`). What I want to do is prevent the user from entering the same categories.

My `CategoriesController` looks like :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Library;

namespace Library.Controllers
{
    public class CategoriesController : Controller
    {
        private LibraryDbEntities1 db = new LibraryDbEntities1();

        // GET: Categories
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Category.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Categories/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);

            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Categories/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Category.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExcecuteScalar().To)

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);

            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Categories/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Categories/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);

            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Categories/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
            db.Category.Remove(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

The index view looks like this:

```
 @model Library.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My question is: how can I prevent the user from entering the same category two times? For example I create a category named "Action", I don't want any other user to be able to create the same category.

Comment: Just add all categories created into a list and then if the user inputs a category check if the list already  `.Contains` that category.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax? I've tried it but I really need help...

Comment: Can you add the code that adds categories?

Comment: What's the point to create a list when all the categories are already stored in the db? Just ask your db context if the new category exists. But this is just part of the problem. You need to check also if during an update the user changes the updated category name to a name already present.

Comment: @MathevHD I have posted the code downbelow

Comment: @Steve I just need to prevent the user from entering the same category name,I want a simple solution in the index.cshtml file. Is it possible?

Comment: You have two options. Put an unique index on the category name so it is the db itself that rejects the update (try/catch required) otherwise add the logic to check for invalid updates in your CS file.

Comment: @Steve is it possible for you to help me via Skype? I would be so thankful..

Comment: @Steve I understand, I did not know but thanks for informing me! And your solution worked now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As I have said in the comments above you have two options. One is to add an unique index to the CategoryName field. This will force the db to reject invalid updates. Of course this means that you have an exception to handle in your code.

I prefer to handle this situation in code avoiding exceptions when possible.
This involves, for the Create action, checking the database if a CategoryName equal to the one proposed exists or not.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Check if the cat name exists or not
        var cat = db.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == category.CategoryName);
        if(cat == null)
        {
            db.Category.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            // Add here the logic required to inform your user about the problem
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Duplicate Category Name";
            
        }
    }
    return View(category);
 }
```

But you have the same problem in the Edit action. Here as well you should prevent your user to change an existing CategoryName into another existing CategoryName but NOT if the one present in the database is the same that you user is editing.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,CategoryName")] Category category)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var cat = db.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == category.CategoryName  
                                             && x.Id != category.Id)
        if(cat == null)
        {
            db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            // Inform your user about the problem
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Duplicate category Name";
        }
    }
    return View(category);
}
```

Finally you can inform your user inside the .cshtml adding a specific DIV with the error message stored in the ViewBag. You can, of course, add some style/css class (red background/color) to draw the user attention to the message.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))
    {
        <div>
        <p>
            <h3>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</h3>
        </p>
        </div>
    }
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
```

Comment: Its working now! But I cannot infrom the user about the problem I tried the following on Create:   else
                {
                    // Add here the logic required to inform your user about the problem
                                       Console.WriteLine("This Category already exist.");

                }

Comment: No, you can simply put the error message in a ViewBag and then in the .cshtml file check if this ViewBag is not null or empty and then display the DIV with the included message

Comment: should I use the same use .cshtml on Edit as well?